# For 'non-trivial' power series, why are term-by-term differentiation & integration done on intervals, even if the series converges everywhere?

Tags: calculus, power-series, uniform-convergence, uniform-continuity

Let $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n$; suppose $f$ has a radius of convergence $R\in [0,\infty]$. Power series are uniformly continuous on the interior of their disk of convergence, permitting among other operations term-by-term differentiation and integration. However, even if ${R}=\infty$, I have only ever seen results that allow term-by-term operations on bounded intervals. This is usually sufficient but I wanted to double-check why this is the case.

My intuition is that the only polynomials that are uniformly continuous on all of $\mathbb{R}$ are linear or constant polynomials: this can easily be proved from the definition of uniform continuity. So even if the series converges everywhere, if it is 'non-linear' in the sense that $a_k\ne 0$ for some $k\ge 2$, then the partial sums are not uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, which means the operations must be done 'locally' on a bounded interval. Is this correct, roughly speaking?

Comment: I don't think power series are uniformly continuous (or uniformly convergent either) on the interior of their disk of convergence. However, they converge uniformly on any *compact* subset of the disk of convergence. This is what is needed in most applications such as termwise integration. The interval of integration is, after all, a compact set. Also, continuity is always uniform on a compact set.

Comment: A subtlety is that every point of the interior of the disk of convergence is also a point of a compact disk contained in the disk of convergence. This makes the theory click.

Comment: In a word, *Yes* the content of your last sentence is correct.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, ah you're right. I said 'interior' because I wanted to stay away from the boundary, but what you said rings a bell and seems correct.

Comment: I do not quite understand your question. However, the statement in the title is not quite correct. For example $\cos(x)$ is real-analytic and uniformly continuous (as is any periodic continuous function).

Comment: @SeverinSchraven apologies, maybe I should refine my title. My question is: why are term-by-term int and diff only done on closed & bounded intervals.